# Update user field in active directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

In my windows server , there are around 1500 users , I have a problem that I would like to fix , please advise.

I would like to update all the e-mail field ( user a/c)  in bulk , for example , the current email field is tom.chan@email.com , I would like to change all email address to their corresponding user name to "user name  + @email.com" , all these user detail are in active direcotry , can advise what can I do ?

eg.
tom.chan@email.com   ==> user1@email.com ;amy.yuen@email.com   ==> user2@email.com ; jacky.hung@email.com ==> user3@email.com